# Transition Effect onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to add a transition effect to this code. What it does is that when you hit a swatch color, the product changes from the original black color to another color. However, there is no ease in transition so it's a very hard transition. Where would I add transition?

```
<script>
    function changeImage(imgName) {
        image = document.getElementById('imgDisp');
        image.src = imgName;
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    span { 
        display:inline-block;
    }
    span:hover { 
        cursor: pointer; 
        color: #999999; 
        text-align:left;
    }
</style>
<span onclick="changeImage('{{'pink-small.png' | asset_url}}')"> 
    <img src="{{'swatch-1.png' | asset_url}}">
    Pink
</span>
<span onclick="changeImage('{{'black-small.png' | asset_url}}')"> 
    <img src="{{'swatch-2.png' | asset_url}}">
    Black
</span>
<span onclick="changeImage('{{'brown-small.png' | asset_url}}')"> 
    <img src="{{'swatch-3.png' | asset_url}}">
    Brown
</span>
<img id="imgDisp" src="{{'black-small.png' | asset_url}}">
```

Comment: You’re trying to transition between images? That’s not very easy, unfortunately; you’ll need to create a second image, position it over top of the other, and animate its opacity.

Comment: Is it important to use images for this? If they are just squares of colour, that seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve the desired effect is to have two image `div`s on top of one another. Set the lower `div` to the target image and fade out the top `div`. Once the top `div` is faded out, switch it to the target image as well and immediately restore its opacity. Since your post was tagged `jquery`, I'm going to use its transition functions in my example (Credit to TinyGiant for the swatch code).

```js
function changeImage(url) {
  $img = $('#imgDisp');
  $imgfi = $('#imgDispFadeIn');
  $imgfi.attr('src', url);
  $img.fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $img.attr('src', url)
    $img.fadeIn(0);
  });
}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
#imgContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#imgDisp,
#imgDispFadeIn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#imgDisp {
  z-index: 10;
}
.swatch {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.swatch.pink {
  background: pink;
}
.swatch.black {
  background: black;
}
.swatch.brown {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
<span onclick="changeImage('//lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1')">  
  <div class="swatch pink"></div>
</span>
<span onclick="changeImage('//lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2')">  
  <div class="swatch black"></div>
</span>
<span onclick="changeImage('//lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/3')"> 
  <div class="swatch brown"></div>
</span>
<div id="imgContainer">
  <img id="imgDisp" src='//lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1' />
  <img id="imgDispFadeIn" src="" />
</div>
```